# Changing y-axis ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, seaborn

I'm working on some data analysis and I'm trying to make some changes to the y-axis of my plot. I'm using Seaborn and using `distplot()`.
Currently this is my plot:

[image: image1]

but I'm trying to achieve this

[image: image2]

Am wondering is there a specific argument I need to include in `distplot()`, or is there some formatting method I could use?

Comment: `distplot` returns a matplotlib axes object. You can then do `ax.set_yticks()` and `ax.set_yticklabels()`

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you!

Comment: In this case you would want `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator` and `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.000025))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit y ticks with `ax.set_yticks` (or `plt.yticks`) as here:

```
custom_ticks = [0, 0.03, 0.1, 0.16, 0.23, 0.27, 0.32, 0.35, 0.39, 0.41]
ax.set_yticks(custom_ticks)
```

So this default plot:

[image]

becomes:

[image]